# Removing output of 'find' command failures

Tags: shell, unix, find

I'm currently writing a script that will search the PATH for specific program name, then output all paths for that program (may have multiple executables). 
What I've come up with is `find $path -name programName`. Given the test input, while it does generate the correct outputs, it also outputs `No such file or directory` lines for the directories in path that don't have the program. Is there any way to remove it?

Thanks!

Edit: this script is meant to mimic the "which -a" command, if that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend the following command since you are looking for programs:

```
find "$path" -type f -name programName 2>/dev/null
```

where `2>/dev/null` mute your `stderr` 
(for more info: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html).

to force `find` to return only files since you might have a folder called `programName`, with your current command it will be picked up by the find command.

Also, what you could add is the `-executable` option if not available use:  `-perm /u+x` to add the constraint that you are looking for files and those files should be executable.

```
find "$path" -type f -name programName -executable 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: The `-executable` part is a nice touch. ++

Comment: Thanks! ;-) ;-) he could add more constraints using `file` command etc ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
find "$path" -name programName -type f 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Use of unquoted variables in teaching resources is perhaps questionable. You may change `$path` to `"$path"`.

Comment: Also, when you're narrowing down your results to just files, you may use `-type f` to do the filtering.